# Categories: A Greenhorn Question on Strategy (Not Code)

Tags: categories, tags, development-strategy

Im having an issue in my category set-up logic

Let's say I sell new/used (including Vintage) Drums/Drum Parts wherein a user can search by  new, used or by individual part. So let's say they choose to search by individual part on Cymbals. The search results page should then display a listing of Cymbals should also be  grouped by new/used? Right?

So, in setting up my categories I'm coming up with this

### New

- Drum Sets
- Cymbals
- Toms

### Used

- Drum Sets
- Cymbals
- Toms

But this seems redundant to me. Can I not achieve my objective WITHOUT all this duplication?  So before I go hacking away at this I thought I would get a few pointers from my peers.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve the same with out the duplication in two ways:

- create a custom taxonomy for condition (new,used)
- use a custom field for condition (new,used)

both ways you only need to create each category only once and filter by condition.